# Pouchdb pagination

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I am looking for a way to paginate in pouchdb by specifying the number of the page that I want.

The closest example I came across is this:

```js
var options = {limit : 5};
function fetchNextPage() {
  pouch.allDocs(options, function (err, response) {
    if (response && response.rows.length > 0) {
      options.startkey = response.rows[response.rows.length - 1].id;
      options.skip = 1;
    }
  });
}
```

It assumes however that you are paginating one page after the other and calling this consecutively several times.

What I need instead is a way to retrieve page 5 for example, with a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy answer to the question. A small slice from [3.2.5.6. Jump to Page](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/pagination.html#jump-to-page)

> One drawback of the linked list style pagination is that you can’t
> pre-compute the rows for a particular page from the page number and
> the rows per page. Jumping to a specific page doesn’t really work. Our
> gut reaction, if that concern is raised, is, “Not even Google is doing
> that!” and we tend to get away with it. Google always pretends on the
> first page to find 10 more pages of results. Only if you click on the
> second page (something very few people actually do) might Google
> display a reduced set of pages. If you page through the results, you
> get links for the previous and next 10 pages, but no more.
> Pre-computing the necessary startkey and startkey_docid for 20 pages
> is a feasible operation and a pragmatic optimization to know the rows
> for every page in a result set that is potentially tens of thousands
> of rows long, or more.

If you are lucky and every document has an ordered sequence number, then a view could be constructed to easily navigate pages.

Another strategy is to precompute (preload) a range of keys, which is more reasonable but is complicated.  The snippet below creates a trivial database which can be paged through via nav links.

There are 5 documents per page, and each "chapter" has 10 pages.  `computePages` performs the look ahead

```js
// look ahead and cache startkey for pages.
async function computePages(startPage, perPage, lookAheadPages, startKey) {
  let options = {
    limit: perPage * lookAheadPages,
    include_docs: false,
    reduce: false
  };
  // adjust. This happens when a requested page has no key cached.
  if (startKey !== undefined) {
    options.startkey = startKey;
    options.skip = perPage; // not ideal, but tolerable probably?
  }
  const result = await db.allDocs(options);
  // use max to prevent result overrun
  // only the first key of each page is stored
  const max = Math.min(options.limit, result.rows.length)
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i += perPage) {
    page_keys[startPage++] = result.rows[i].id;
  }
}
```

`page_keys` provides a key/value store mapping page number to start key.  Usually anything other than 1 for `skip` is red flag however this is reasonable here - we won't be skipping say a 100 documents right?

I just threw this together so it is imperfect and likely buggy, but it does demonstrate page navigation generally.

```js
function gel(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

// canned test documents
function getDocsToInstall() {
  let docs = [];
  // doc ids are a silly sequence of characters.
  for (let i = 33; i < 255; i++) {
    docs.push({
      _id: `doc-${String.fromCharCode(i)}`
    });
  }
  return docs;
}

// init db instance
let db;
async function initDb() {
  db = new PouchDB('test', {
    adapter: 'memory'
  });
  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());
}

// documents to show per page
const rows_per_page = 5;
// how many pages to preload into the page_keys list.
const look_ahead_pages = 10;
// page key cache: key = page number, value = document key
const page_keys = {};
// the current page being viewed
let page_keys_index = 0;
// track total rows available to prevent rendering links beyond available pages.
let total_rows = undefined;
async function showPage(page) {
  // load the docs for this page
  let options = {
    limit: rows_per_page,
    include_docs: true,
    startkey: page_keys[page] // page index is computed
  };
  let result = await db.allDocs(options);
  // see renderNav. Here, there is NO accounting for live changes to the db.
  total_rows = total_rows || result.total_rows;
  // just display the doc ids.
  const view = gel('view');
  view.innerText = result.rows.map(row => row.id).join("\n");
}

// look ahead and cache startkey for pages.
async function computePages(startPage, perPage, lookAheadPages, startKey) {
  let options = {
    limit: perPage * lookAheadPages,
    include_docs: false,
    reduce: false
  };
  // adjust. This happens when a requested page has no key cached.
  if (startKey !== undefined) {
    options.startkey = startKey;
    options.skip = perPage; // not ideal, but tolerable probably?
  }
  const result = await db.allDocs(options);
  // use max to prevent result overrun
  // only the first key of each page is stored
  const max = Math.min(options.limit, result.rows.length)
  for (let i = 0; i < max; i += perPage) {
    page_keys[startPage++] = result.rows[i].id;
  }
}


// show page links and optional skip backward/forward links.
let last_chapter;
async function renderNav() {
  // calculate which page to start linking.
  const chapter = Math.floor(page_keys_index / look_ahead_pages);
  if (chapter !== last_chapter) {
    last_chapter = chapter;
    const start = chapter * look_ahead_pages;
    let html = "";
    // don't render more page links than possible.
    let max = Math.min(start + look_ahead_pages, total_rows / rows_per_page);

    // render prev link if nav'ed past 1st chapter.
    if (start > 0) {
      html = `<a href="javascript:void" onclick="navTo(${start-1})">&lt;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;`;
    }

    for (let i = start; i < max; i++) {
      html += `<a href="javascript:void" onclick="navTo(${i})">${i+1}</a>&nbsp;`;
    }
    // if more pages available, render the 'next' link
    if (max % look_ahead_pages === 0) {
      html += `&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void" onclick="navTo(${start+look_ahead_pages})">&gt;</a>&nbsp;`;
    }

    gel("nav").innerHTML = html;
  }
}

async function navTo(page) {
  if (page_keys[page] === undefined) {
    // page key not cached - compute more page keys.
    await computePages(page, rows_per_page, look_ahead_pages, page_keys[page - 1]);
  }
  page_keys_index = page;
  await showPage(page_keys_index);
  renderNav();

}

initDb().then(async() => {
  await navTo(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<pre id="view"></pre>
<hr/>
<div id="nav">
  </nav>
```